# Eclipse Linux Launch failed. Binary not found

Tags: linux, eclipse, compiler-errors, eclipse-cdt

So I have this problem that seams to be not to uncommon after spending some time on Google.

Basicly when I try to run my application I get a pop up saying " Launch failed. Binary not found"

I have tried most things on that people have suggested but I have a hard time finding anything other than people suggesting to change the binary parser and to make sure to use build all. Here's a list of things I've checked to avoid these answers again:

- I have of course built my project before pressing run. Also cleaned up, rebuilt and restarted everything I can
- Changed binary parser to ELF parser as I am using xubuntu through virtualbox
- Eclipse returns 0 build error and 0 warnings. Also tried with a hello world project
- Made sure my PATH variables are correct

And at the moment that's about it. I've looked at the first 5 pages of the search results for "Eclipse Launch failed. Binary not found" on Google without success.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a change in how Ubuntu handles executables. They are now built with PIE, meaning that the executable loads at different addresses each time. The result though is that the executable looks like a library to Eclipse CDT.

You can try right-clicking directly on the executable and choose Run As -> C/C++ Application (or Debug As ->).

It is when you right-click on the project and choose Run As / Debug As that CDT fails to find any actual executables.

Follow [Bug 512822](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=512822) for updates.

Comment: Thanks this helps alot. Unfortunly it did not solve the problem. I am however dumb as I have realized that no executeable is actually built. Eclipse says everything is okey but when I look in the target folder nothing is there